# Proving $AAS \Rightarrow$ two triangles are congruent

Tags: geometry

I have been looking around for a proof by contradiction on $AAS$ congruence in neutral geometry, but can not find any sources on it. Does anyone know how the proof by contradiction goes for angle angle side congruence in neutral geometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have a triangle with one side length $c$ and two angles $\alpha$ and  $\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the angle opposite $c$.  We must show that this triangle is unique up to congruence.

Let us construct this triangle.

We start by drawing segment $AB$ of length $c$.  Then draw a ray starting at $A$ which forms angle $\alpha$ with segment $AB$.  So far everything is unique up to congruence.

Now to complete the proof, we must show that there is at most one point $C$ on the above ray such that angle BCA is equal to $\gamma$.  If there were 2 such points $C$ and $C'$, with angles $BCA$ and $BC'A$ both equal to $\gamma$, then angles of triangle $BCC'$ add up to more than $180^{\circ}$. This is a contradiction in neutral geometry.